# Source Specific Multicast под nasm

Tags: linux, ассемблер

Код для подключения по Source Specific Multicast под nasm
    global _start

```
section .data

add:    db 0x4b, 0x9c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa, 0x32, 0x81, 0x5a
len:    equ $-add

section .bss

buffer: resb 1025
buffer_len: equ 1024
buff_read:  resb 1025

section .text

_start: 

    mov rax, 41
    mov rdi, 2
    mov rsi, 2
    mov rdx, 0
    syscall

    mov dword [rsp-4], eax
    mov dword [rsp-8], 0xefc346b ;group_ip 239.195.70.11

    mov rax, 54                 ;sys_setsockopt
    mov rdi, [rsp-4]
    mov rsi, 1
    mov rdx, 2
    lea r10, [rsp-8]
    mov r8, 4
    syscall

    xor rcx, rcx
    mov byte [rsp-26], 0x27         ;IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP  39
    mov byte [rsp-25], 0x00         ;IPPROTO_IP 0
    mov byte [rsp-24], 0x02         ;af_inet
    mov word [rsp-22], 0x9c41       ;port 40001
    mov dword [rsp-18], 0x5a8132a   ;source_ip 10.50.129.90
    mov qword [rsp-16], rcx

    mov rax, 49                 ;sys_bind
    mov rdi, [rsp-4]
    lea rsi, [rsp-24]
    mov rdx, 16
    syscall

    mov rax, 54                 ;sys_setsockopt
    mov rdi, [rsp-4]
    mov rsi, 0                  ;ipproto_ip
    mov rdx, [rsp-26]           ;IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP 0x27
    mov r10, [add]
    mov r8, len
    syscall
...
```

при проверке через gdb, последний syscall возвращает ошибку -92, в чем причина?

Answer (score 1):

`grep 92 usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h`

```
...
#define ENOPROTOOPT     92      /* Protocol not available */
...
```

мультикаст походу в ядре отключен